# How does one, within a sequence of digits, count how many times a digit appears thats value is exactly one less than the previous digit's one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, reduce

code:

```js
function OneDecremented(num) { 
  num = num.toString()
  var count = 0

  for(i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
    if(num[i - 1] - num[i] === 1){
      count++
    }
  }
  return count

}
console.log(OneDecremented(9876541110))
```

so I'm struggling to understand two things:

1. what's the difference between i and num[i]
2. I don't understand how the calculation is happening inside the if statement, could someone break it down?

sorry if these questions sound too silly, I'm new to JS and couldn't really get my head around the arithmetic calculations. Thank you for you time.

Comment: Welcome to SO and I'm glad you got a successful answer. It would be curteous to acknowledge/upvote any other users who took the time to help by answering.

Comment: @Mitya ... OP has not enough reputation for voting (even got downvoted once); but let me assist.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Thank you, very kind. I didn't realise (even after all this time) that noobs couldn't vote yet. That seems odd; they should be encouraged to be responsive to answers given, I'd have thought (in addition to accepting an answer.)

Comment: @Mitya I tried but it wouldn't let me. Thank you for your time <3

Comment: No worries - I hadn't realised you couldn't vote as a noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is poorly written for few reasons, but most importantly, it leaks the `i` reference globally so, let's start with a better version:

```
function OneDecremented(num) {
  var str = num.toString();
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i - 1] - str[i] === 1)
      count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Strings, in modern JS, can be accessed like arrays, and the index returns the char at the `index` position:

```
if(str[i - 1] - str[i] === 1)
// is the same as
if ((str.charAt(i - 1) - str.charAt(i)) === 1)
```

Once retrieved each char, the code does an implicit "*char to number*" conversion, thanks to the `-` operator, but if it was a `+` instead, it would've concatenated the two chars as string instead (so, be careful).

It's always better to be explicit, but if you know how `-` works, it does the job for this task.

The loop starts from `1`, and it checks that the char at `i - 1`, which is in the first iteration the char at index `0`, minus the current char, is `1`, meaning the current char is *one less the previous*.

When that's the case, the counter sums up.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! It makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

> what's the difference between i and num[i]

`i` is the iteration key, i.e. 0, 1, 2 etc, for as many characters are in the stringified number. `num[i]` is the character at the index `i` in the string, i.e. `num[i]` where `i` is 0 == `9` (the character in the string at index 0).

> I don't understand how the calculation is happening inside the if statement, could someone break it down?

That says: If the calculation of the number at index `i-1` of the string, minus the current number being considered (at index `i` in the string) minus is 1, then increment `count`.

Step by step for the actual number used:

- 9 - has no previous character; calculation (undefined - 9) does not equate to 1
- 8 - previous char is 9;  (9 - 8) == 1; increment `count`
- 7 - ditto
- 6 - ditto
- 5 - ditto
- 4 - ditto
- 1 - previous char is 4; calculation (4 - 1) does not equate to 1
- 1 - previous char is 1; calculation (1 - 1) does not equate to 1
- 1 - ditto
- 0 - previous char is 1;  (1 - 0) == 1; increment `count`

Answer (score 1):

Andrea and Mitya already nailed it.

The next step could be switching to a [*first class*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function) based approach like using a specific [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) method such as [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works).

Such an approach, if implemented correctly, usually improves readability/maintainability of code and allows for better code-reuse.

For the example provided by the OP one could write two functions, the actual method, which gets the count and the above mentioned first class reducer functionality. Since `reduce` is a standard way of how arrays can be processed the arguments-precedence of the reducer/callback is well specified too ...

```
[/* ... */].reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, currentlyProcessedArray) {

  // implement reducer/aggregation/accumulator logic here.

  // the return value serves as the
  // new `accumulator` value within
  // the next iteration step.

  // thus, always return something! ... e.g ...

  return (accumulator + currentValue); 
});
```

```js
function aggregatePrecursorAndDecrementedSuccessorCount(count, char, idx, arr) {

  const precursorValue = Number(arr[idx - 1]);
  const incrementedCurrentValue = (Number(char) + 1);
  const isValidCount = (precursorValue === incrementedCurrentValue);

  return (count + (isValidCount ? 1 : 0));
//return (count + Number(isValidCount)); // cast boolean value to either 1 or 0.
}

function getPrecursorAndDecrementedSuccessorCount(int) {
  return String(int) // - assure/typecast always a/into string value.
    .split('')       // - split string value into an array of single characters.
    .reduce(aggregatePrecursorAndDecrementedSuccessorCount, 0);
}

console.log(getPrecursorAndDecrementedSuccessorCount(9876541110));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to a different approach! Really helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function OneDecremented(num) { 
  num = num.toString()
  var count = 0

  for(i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
    if(num[i - 1] - num[i] === 1){
      count++
    }
  }
  return count

}
console.log(OneDecremented(5915582))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).